# Connection pooling in google cloud sql using jdbc

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to develop an application using google cloud sql and cloud endpoints , from the google cloud sql documentation i observed that the connector for google cloud sql does not provide any connection pooling mechanism , i tried searching online to get any possible tutorial or documentation that provides a pooling mechanism but no result , The google documentation just states that you should close connections in the finally block without any connection pooling configuration , I also came across pooling libraries like BoneCp, TomcatDbCp , i'm considering using those options but im not sure about their compatibility with google cloud sql . My front end is a web application and pooling is a must for my application , Please any thoughts or suggestions are welcomed .

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL itself does not provide connection pooling, however any connection pooling system that supports JDBC will successfully use Cloud SQL. One limitiation, mentioned on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526563/3645370), is that no native threads are allowed. This user recommends Tomcat DBCP, so that seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah I saw the link , will probably try it out .